# Code contract is not showing errors

Tags: c#, code-contracts

I found a strange behavior in contract code tool in VS.

The image above shows no error after building the project:
[image]

but when I add some code on, it shows the error:
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Please show us your code so we have something to work with.

Comment: @ionutioio my code is in the images.

Comment: I'm sorry but no image is visible on my end.

Comment: Image1: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WVgkX.png
Image2: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fpVev.png

Comment: I can't explain this weird behavior but I do recommend you rethink your use of contracts in the Sum method. You're expecting Contract.Ensures to validate _invocations_ of the method, but that's not its job so I'm not surprised that it's acting flaky. You should instead be relying on Contract.Requires to validate invocations (but of course keep Contract.Ensures to validate the result).